# Hyperlinks activated with the right permission?

Tags: hyperlink, item-level-permissions

Is it possible to create hyperlinks that can only be clicked if you belong to that organization / have permission?

We have a list of all departments at the company. We want the employees to be able to see all the departments, but can only click on the ones they belong to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry... That wont work without some CSOM Magic. You could manage something like that with JS. You could put placeholders on the page and create links for these sites from search via a rest querry, if you can identify them propperly - Search would be preffered since you dont have to mess with a datasource that Needs permissions in sync.